# Invalid block tag: 'endblock' django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am getting this error (Invalid block tag: 'endblock') pointing to the line number 12. I have no idea why, because my blocks seems okay to me.

```
1{% extends 'base.html' %} <!-- tells that you use the base for most of the look -->
3   
4       {% block jumbotron}
5           <div class="jumbotron">
6             <div class="container">
7               <h1>Connect your world</h1>
8               <p>This is a template .</p>
9               <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
10            </div>
11          </div>
12      {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Do you need an extra `%` for `endblock` ? Are you missing a `%` in `block jumbotron` ?

Answer (score 9):

You should add `%` here:

```
{% block jumbotron}
```

to became:

```
{% block jumbotron %}
```

Check template [syntax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#for-template-blocks) used in Django for more info.

Answer (score 2):

```
{% block jumbotron}
```

You need to correct the syntax. You forgot to put `%` in your block statement.

```
{% block jumbotron %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was `{% endblock %}` problem, it should be `{% block base_content %}{% endblock base_content %}` or else it fails with error `Invalid block tag: 'endblock' django`

Answer (score 0):

I would use the template tags like below:

```
{% block jumbotron %}

    <div></div>

{% endblock jumbotron %}
```